# How to get Injectable to generate dependency injection for third party Abstract class thats using factory constructors

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, code-generation, injectable

I am trying to register the class below with the package **Injectable**.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';


@injectable
class IWantToBeRegistered {
  final File file;
  IWantToBeRegistered({
    required this.file,
  });
}
```

I get the response below:

```
[WARNING] injectable_generator:injectable_config_builder on bin/service_locator.dart:
Missing dependencies in your_project/bin/service_locator.dart

[MachineCodeWriter] depends on unregistered type [File] from dart:io

Did you forget to annotate the above class(s) or their implementation with @injectable? 
or add the right environment keys?
```

I have attempted registering `File` as a third party type but with no luck.
In the [documentation of Injectable](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable#Registering-third-party-types) it does say it's possible to register it manually in the configure function, but I was unable to find a *working* example and failed to implement it successfully by myself.

The project is a command line app in Dart and I am using the SDK and package versions below:

```yaml
Dart SDK version: 2.15.1 (stable)
get_it: ^7.2.0
injectable: ^1.5.0
injectable_generator: ^1.5.0
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RegisterModule` for this purpose.

you can check how you can use RegisterModule for injectable [from here](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable#using-a-register-module-for-third-party-dependencies)

```
@module  
abstract class RegisterModule {  
   YourThirdParty getThirdPartyObjectInstance(TypeOfThirdParty typedObject, @factoryParam String url) => YourThirdParty(obj, url);  
}
```